# Backup Publishing Pages and its content

Tags: 2010, publishing-page, backup

Is there any way to backup Publishing pages and it's contents (including webparts) in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Are you asking about backing up for the purposes of disaster recovery or backing up in case someone botches a content update?

Comment: backup to restore in another web application (transfer pages and it's data from development server to production server)

Answer (score 1):

The official stance from Microsoft is that content moves backward (that is, from Production, to QA to Dev) while code moves forward (dev to QA to Prod) so that production-ready content is only created once and in the environment that it will actually render in.  Content is generally moved backward via Publishing jobs or a simple copying of the content database.

However, in your case, you might want to look into the Export Site option in Backup and Recovery in Central Administration.  This will create an export of the site that you can import where you want using [`Import-SPWeb`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) command.

If open-source tools are an option, [Gary Lapoint's SharePoint automation](http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx) tools are excellent and might offer other options, particularly the [`Copy-SPList`](http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2010&Cmdlet=Copy-SPList) command.